# advanced custom field -wordpress+ repeater

Tags: wordpress, slider, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I combined a slider with the repeater fields.
under the repeater I have 2 subfields. one called “image” and the other “title”

this slider has a class called “selected-item” that dynamically appear when an image is selected. (when this class is on an image the image change it’s size).

How can I define that when the class “selected-item” is on some image also the “title” form the same row of the image will appear?

this is the code the displays the images:

```
    <?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
 $i = 1;
if( have_rows('carousel_images') ):
    // loop through the rows use_cases_fields data
    while ( have_rows('carousel_images') ) : the_row();
          $title=get_sub_field('image_carousel_discription');
        $image = get_sub_field('image_carousel1');

        if( !empty($image) ):
            // vars

            // thumbnail
            $thumb = $image;

            $i++;

            ?>

   <h1 data-row="< echo $i; >">   <?php echo $title ?>     </h1>
                <li> <a href="#home"><img  data-row="< echo $i; >" src="<?php echo $thumb ?>"/></a> </li>


        <?php endif; ?>



        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

?>

Comment: I would include a callback in your jQuery slider to find the "data-row" attr and then display the h1 of the same "data-row" value. What jQuery are you using to slide through your images?

Comment: do u mean which version?

Comment: No, sorry. I should have been more clear. Which slider are you using? Is it a plugin, a jQuery library or what?

Comment: it's a jquery library called jquery sky carousel

Comment: The answer is below. You should be able to listen to the click on your carousel or run a function on a callback of your slider.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the title hidden in the beginning and then show the title when selected-item class is applied. If h1 is going to be always next to the image tag then use the `+` selector.

```
h1 { display: none; }
.selected-item + h1 { display: block; }
```

Or you can detect a class change event using jquery.

```js
function checkForChanges()
{
    if ($('img').hasClass('selected-item'))
        $('h1').css('display','block');
    else
        setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
}

checkForChanges();

$("#click").on('click', function(){
    $('img').addClass("selected-item");
});
```

```css
    h1 { display: none; } /* Keep the title hidden in the beginning */
     /* Show the title when selected-item class is applied */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" width="100" height="100">
<h1>title</h1>
<div id="click">click me</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't have a relation between the title and the img, when the class "selected-item" is on image it's only on the image and not on the title

Comment: Then please add a similar class to h1, like you are adding it to the image. and using that class hide h1 tag. or if h1 is always going to be next to the image tag then you can use the `+` selector also like `.selected-item + h1 { display: block; }`

Comment: the problem is all the titles from all the rows are appear when selected item class is active, I need that only the title from the same row of the selected image will appear when the "selected-item" class is active on the picture.